# extract token from string, paste to input field

Tags: javascript

I want to click on a "●" delimited div with an id of "textDiv", extract the first token and paste it to an input field with an id of "mem-name".

```
<div id="textDiv" onclick = "grabName();">Jones, Bob ● Smith, Paul</div> 

<script>
function grabName() {
var MyDiv1 = Document.getElementById('textDiv');    
var moniker = MyDiv1.split("●");
var firstToken = moniker [0];
document.getElementById("mem-name").value = firstToken;
}   
</script>

<input type="text" id = "mem-name" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close.  You have to use the `innerHTML` of the div.  Also you have a typo in `Document.getElementById` as document is lower case.

```html
<div id="textDiv" onclick = "grabName();">Jones, Bob ● Smith, Paul</div> 

<script>
function grabName() {
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('textDiv').innerHTML;    
var moniker = MyDiv1.split("●");
var firstToken = moniker [0];
document.getElementById("mem-name").value = firstToken;
}   
</script>

<input type="text" id = "mem-name" />
```